# Where does File Explorer (Windows 10 Pro) store its Index of items displayed in its root?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Context:

A few years ago I installed some utility that allowed to mount Google Drive contents from multiple accounts.
IIRC it was called Odrive.
This created a root item in in File Explorer named after the program.

Eventually, I found a more fitting alternative to this application and I uninstalled it.
All application files were gone as far as I was aware, but I didn't discover until much later that the root item in the File Explorer somehow remained even though clicking or double-clicking it produced no result.

The only thing I could do to it was select properties, and at one point I was able to rename it, by changing the text and hitting Apply in the popup.

Here is where I made a mistake - at one point I decided to remove everything in the Name field and hit Apply, just to see if it would somehow error out.

It didn't error out, and it actually save the name as blank.

However now, not only am I not able to open it, I am also not able to rename it anymore because Apply does not light up as available even with changed text. So now it just exits as a blank Yellow folder.

If before I may have been able to name it something very unique, and then search the registry for it, to see where it is to hopefully remove it - now its unsearchable.

Right clicking on the item:

- Expand (does nothing)
- Open in a new window (does nothing)
- Pin to quick access (actually causes an error "Explorer.EXE ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" 'OK')
- Copy (Pasting does nothing)
- Properties ( [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9A2B.png) )

Since I cant search for it by its name. is there some location(s) in regedit or elsewhere that I can look through to find this orphaned component and finally get rid of it?

Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Items like that are inserted into the `Desktop` namespace via the registry.

Items that are common to all users are the GUID-named subkeys of:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`

Items that are added on a per-user basis are found in the corresponding key under HKCU:
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`

So open `REgistry Editor` and start by checking the `HKCU` key, as on a fresh install, it will only have an entry for `OneDrve` named `{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}`:

[image]

The others you see in my screenshot are custom items I've added. With luck, like the `OneDrive` entry, it will have a human-readable value to identify it. If you don't find it there, check the subkeys of the `HKLM` key.

When you've found it, before deleting, select the GUID-named key, press `F2` to rename, copy the name to the clipboard, and then deletDee the key.

Then collapse the registry tree, `Ctrl+F` to display the `FInd` dialog, paste the `GUID` from the clipboard, de-select `Names` and `Values` so you're only searching key names, and start the search. Delete every occureance you find.

Comment: For testing the GUID registry keys marked on left side in the screenshot, which is the correct one just append something like an underscore to it's end, that should "deactivate" it. If it is something you want to keep you can simply restore the old state.